# Proof of Riemann Integration involving convex differentiable function

Tags: calculus, integration

> Define the convex function by:
>
> A function $f$ is convex on an interval if for $a$, $x$ and $b$ in the
>   interval with $a<x<b$, we have $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} <
>  \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Let $f$ be a convex differentiable function. Prove that if $u$ is any continuous function, then $$\frac{1}{a}\int_0^a f(u(t))dt \geq f\Big(\frac{1}{a}\int_0^a u(t) dt\Big)$$

Hint:Consider the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at point $(c, f(c))$ where $$c = \frac{1}{a}\int_0^a u(t) dt$$

I don't know where I should start? I don't even understanding the hint....

Comment: Your definition of convex can be restated as "$f$ lies below its secant lines". A related fact about differentiable convex functions is that they lie *above* their tangent lines. If you want to use the hint, this would probably be a useful fact to have at your disposal. (As an aside, this is a special case of a famous result called Jensen's inequality.)